# How to handle API endpoint access with Keycloak

Tags: python, flask, keycloak, flask-restful, api-key

I'm working on an application with the following setup:

- Keycloak with my client, some groups, users and roles created
- Flask to create my API endpoints

What I want to achieve is my user/client gets authenticated by Keycloak and given an API Key with authorization to some specific endpoints.

I've searched for some documentation, examples or best practices on how achieve that with Keycloak but without success.

Could you clarify for me if what I want to achieve makes sense and the best way to do it with my setup?

Comment: Why do you need to use Keycloak for authentication (authN) AND API key for authorization (authZ)? Why do you need to use both and not just one (keycloak/api-key) for authN and authZ?

Comment: „*Why do you need to use Keycloak for authentication (authN) AND API key for authorization (authZ)?*“ – @JanGaraj — Would you care to elaborate on the pros and cons of the alternative? Your comment sounds like you could have the basis for an upvote-winning, *accepted* answer. TIA.

Comment: Take a look at [python-keycloak](https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/) and [python-keycloak-client](https://python-keycloak-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). These two libraries may help.